# How can I render LaTex in to actual math in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, latex

I am writing a plugin for simple math which will show symbols and user can use and write formulas. Am done till here. I got struck in how to get it displayed in CKEditor? Even I hard code some latex like "editor.insertHtml( " \displaystyle{ { {3} \over {4} } } ");" it does not convert to math inside of CKEditor.

I know that I need to include this library "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML". But not understanding how to include this in CKEdtior?

Please help!!!

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your answer for future readers).

Comment: Thank you, am using this in my own servers not using the CDN site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax addon from CKEditor addons repository?

Comment: Yes, but I do not want user to write latex code for Math. There should be an UI for them to select whether it's square root or Power of some thing like that.. When they select, I will get the html or latex from it and I can insert into CKEditor.

Comment: There are two another addons in the repository:

- [Math Editor](http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathedit)
- [WIRIS math & science editor](http://ckeditor.com/addon/ckeditorwiris) (Commercial)

Answer (score 0):

[image: view of custom mathjax plugin] there is my repo in github, check it https://github.com/bagana89/CKeditorMathJaxPlugin

Comment: What is this? An answer?

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/311792